# Finding Chebychev coefficients

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, chebyshev-polynomials

To find Chebyshev coefficients I need to compute the following polynomial with $T_k(x)$ being the Chebyshev polynomial. We use that $T_k(\cos(z))=\cos(kz)$
$$
2\int_0^1 T_k(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx=
$$
Now we change the variable $x=\cos(z)\Leftrightarrow z=\cos^{-1}(x)$ and $dz=\cos^{-1}(x)$, $dx=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$. Wouldn't we have because $\cos^{-1}(1)=0,\cos^{-1}(0)=\pi /2$
$$
2 \int_0^{\pi/2}-\cos(kz) dz
$$
I am wondering because my solution says
$$
2 \int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(kz) dz
$$
so I am confused where the "-" is going and would appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply the substitution formula, the lower bounds and the upper bounds must correspond, so you obtain
$$2\int_0^1 T_k(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx=2 \int^0_{\pi/2}\mkern-9mu-\cos(kz)\,\mathrm  dz=2 \int_0^{\pi/2}\mkern -9mu\cos(kz) \,\mathrm dz$$

Comment: Thank you very much!